# Smack 4.2.0 OutgoingChatMessageListener is not getting any call

Tags: android, android-fragments, xmpp, smack, android-listfragment

I am using smack 4.2.0 latest version, here `IncomingChatMessageListener` is working fine but `OutgoingChatMessageListener` is not getting called when I send the message. Can any one suggest me whats the issue?
My code is below

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mXMPPConn);
EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom(mStrJabberID);
Chat chat = chatManager.chatWith(jid);
chatManager.addOutgoingListener(new OutgoingChatMessageListener() {
   @Override
   public void newOutgoingMessage(EntityBareJid to, Message message, Chat chat) 
   {
      System.out.format("OUTGOING: %s.\n", message);
   }
});

chat.send(strMsg);
```

Comment: strange, try enabling logs

Comment: I am also having same issue , let me know if you figured out the issue .

Comment: same issue.. please help if you found the solution... :(

Answer (score 1):

I traced the code and found out there is a bug in `AbstractJidTypeFilter.class` in this version.

Changing your version from Smack 4.2.0 to Smack 4.2.2 should work. 
Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am debugging into the source code of smack. You can try the following:

1. set FromMode.USER to the connection

   ```
   connection.setFromMode(XMPPConnection.FromMode.USER);
   ```
2. set message type before sending message

   ```
   message.setType(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.Type.chat);
   ```

Explain:

1. `AbstractJidTypeFilter` checks the from `jid` of message is full or bare. The connection will set the from `jid` of stanza, default is `null`. (`AbstractXMPPConnection.java#sendStanza`, line 666)
2. `MessageTypeFilter` will check the type of message is chat or normal.